# manipulating dataframe in R to fit specific format

Tags: r, dplyr, transformation

[original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmHpz.png)

[requested output data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIX4p.png)

My current data sets looks looks like the first picture, while i am trying to figure out the code so the data is transformed to look like the second picture.

Comment: Please don't post images of datasets. Include the data as formatted text in your question.

Comment: Not sharing your data for easy replication will not help you to get many useful responses. Nevertheless, you should have a look at the `pivot_longer` function from the `tidyr` package. This function will achieve what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach using `pivot_longer()`

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(Doc_Name = c("Doc1", "Doc2", "Doc3"), 
                 Q1_Value = c("yes", "no", "yes"), 
                 Q1_Text = c("positive", "negative", "positive"), 
                 Q2_Value= as.character(c(1,0,2)), 
                 Q2_Text = c("1 for rate", "0 for rate", "2 for rate"))

#   Doc_Name Q1_Value  Q1_Text Q2_Value    Q2_Text
# 1     Doc1      yes positive        1 1 for rate
# 2     Doc2       no negative        0 0 for rate
# 3     Doc3      yes positive        2 2 for rate
df2 <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Doc_Name, Q1_Text, Q2_Text), names_to = "Question", values_to = "Value") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Doc_Name, Question, Value), values_to = "Text") %>% 
  mutate(Question = str_replace_all(Question, regex("(?<=)_Value.*"), "")) %>% 
  select(Doc_Name, Question, Value, Text)

# Doc_Name Question Value Text      
# <chr>    <chr>    <chr> <chr>     
# 1 Doc1     Q1       yes   positive  
# 2 Doc1     Q1       yes   1 for rate
# 3 Doc1     Q2       1     positive  
# 4 Doc1     Q2       1     1 for rate
# 5 Doc2     Q1       no    negative  
# 6 Doc2     Q1       no    0 for rate
# 7 Doc2     Q2       0     negative  
# 8 Doc2     Q2       0     0 for rate
# 9 Doc3     Q1       yes   positive  
# 10 Doc3     Q1       yes   2 for rate
# 11 Doc3     Q2       2     positive  
# 12 Doc3     Q2       2     2 for rate
```